# A question about perfect group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that if $G = G'$, then $Z$$\left( G/{Z\left( G \right)} \right)=1$.

My attemp is here.

**Fact**: $G' \le N$ if the quotient group $G/N$ is abelian. Since $G = G'$, by the fact, there is no normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is abelian. Suppose that $Z$$\left( G/{Z\left( G \right)} \right)\ne1$. Then, there exists an element 
$1 \ne aZ\left( G \right) \in G/Z\left( G \right)$ such that $aZ\left( G \right)$ commutes $G/Z\left( G \right)$, i.e., $aZ\left( G \right)gZ\left( G \right)=gZ\left( G \right)aZ\left( G \right)$ for every $gZ\left( G \right) \in G/Z\left( G \right)$. This implies that the commutator $\left[ {a,g} \right] \in Z\left( G \right)$. Since $g$ is arbitrary, we have that $\left[ {a,G} \right] \le Z\left( G \right)$. Then, it is easy to see that $\left[ {a,G} \right] \triangleleft G$. Since $\left[ {a,G} \right] \le Z\left( G \right)$ and $G = G'$, $\left[ {a,G} \right] \ne G$. Then, to complete the proof, it is enough to show that $G/\left[ {a,G} \right]$ is abelian. But I can not show.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the three subgroups lemma.

> Let $Z(G/Z(G)) = K/Z(G)$. Then $[K,G] \leq Z(G)$ since $[K/Z(G), G/Z(G)] = 1$. By Three subgroups, $[G,K] = [[G,G],K] \leq [[K,G],G] [[G,K],G] = [[K,G],G] \leq [ Z(G), G ] = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jack Schmidt.