# Commutator subgroup clarification

Tags: group-theory

If $G=G'.$  Show that $Z(G/Z(G))=identity$

I do the following. By the definition of $G^{'}$ we have
$G^{'}=[G,G]=<aba^{-1}b^{-1}, a, b \in G>$.
Assume that $H_{1}\in Z(G/Z(G))$ then $H_{1}(aZ(G))=(aZ(G))H_{1}$
where $H_{1}\in G/Z(G)$ so $H_{1}=xZ(G)$ for some $x\in G,$
then $xZ(G)aZ(G)=aZ(G)xZ(G)$ which implies that
$Z(G)=a^{-1}x^{-1}axZ(G)=Z(G)$ so that $a^{-1}x^{-1}ax \in Z(G).$ 
Now Is it true to say that $G^{'}\subseteq Z(G)$ or what can I do?

Comment: I guess it is fine....

Comment: No. You just have $a^{-1}x^{-1}ax \in Z(G) \cap [G,G]$. While $a$ was arbitrary, $x$ was chosen from $Z_2(G)$. Also $[G,G]=G$ so $Z(G) \cap [G,G] = Z(G)$.

Comment: Is there another idea to this problem?

Comment: I gave a different solution at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629109/a-question-about-perfect-group/629130#629130

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Some ideas putting $\;Z:=Z(G)\;$ for simplicity:

$$xZ\in Z(G/Z)\iff \forall\,g\in G\;,\;\;(xZ)(gZ)=(gZ)(xZ)\iff $$

$$\iff [x,g]:=x^{-1}g^{-1}xg\in Z$$

Now the *actual* meat:

Prove that the map $\;\phi:G\to Z=Z(G)\;,\;\;\phi(g):=[x,g]\;$ is a group homomorphism (you'll need some messing with commutators, but it may even be fun!).

What *can* $\;\ker\phi\;$ possibly be and how does the perfect condition $\;G=G'\;$ kicks in here? What then can you deduce about $\;\phi\;$ ? End the exercise now...